# How to use the 'Free from captvity' option from the intrigue focus

Tags: crusader-kings-2

So I want to free my kinswomen from the King of France's prison but I see no option anywhere, despite having the intrigue focus? Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

If she is part of your court then you should be able to right-click on her portrait and select 'free from captivity', if you can't then shes not part of your court and you can't.